Incorrectly identified as a member of a settlement class
I received notice of a settlement pending for a class-action lawsuit.
I did not meet the definition of people who comprise the class.  Members of the class must have opened an account with a particular financial institution during a specific period of time.  I had never opened account with that institution nor with any other that had merged with it.
I contacted the settlement administrator through a web form.  Weeks letter, I received an email response that "assured" me that I was indeed a member of the class because I had been assigned a member ID number.
I wrote a letter to the court (per the instructions in the settlement notice) objecting to the settlement.  I argued that my erroneous inclusion in the class suggested that the scope of impact was not understood and thus it would be premature to settle.
Almost immediately, a lawyer for the plaintiffs asked me to withdraw my objection.  She pointed out that court had already accepted the determination of who was and wasn't in the class.  We debated it for a while.  In the end, I declined to withdraw my objection.
Why was the lawyer intent on getting me to withdraw my objection?  I can't see any circumstance in which the court would have entertained my objection for even a moment:

If the court accepted my assertion that I'm not a member, then I wouldn't have had standing to object.

If the court rejected my assertion (because the court had already approved the list of class members), then my objection that the class membership is incorrect would have been moot.



Did a member of the defendant's legal team contact you as well? I'm curious as I would think such information would be highly relevant from their perspective. Also, is it possible someone fraudulently opened an account in your name?

@Pyrotechnical:  No, other than a confirmation from the court clerk that my objection had been received, I was contacted only by the plaintiffs' team. I assume that if the defendant's team wanted more information, they would have contacted the plaintiffs' team who represented the settlement class.

@Pyrotechnical: I was able to piece together what had happened afterwards. But it's too long to explain in a comment and I don't think it's relevant to my question about whether the court would/should have considered my objection.

Why go through all this trouble? Someone wants to send you money, take it. Unless they ask for bank information to deposit it (sounds like an identity theft scam), WTP?

@Barmar:  Not that it's relevant to my question, but (1) I already had enough credit monitoring settlements to last the rest of my life, (2) I was bothered on principle by the legal fiction that I was in the class even though I didn't meet the definition of the class (and whether I would be bound by the settlement agreement), and (3) I was concerned that there were bigger problems here. And it turns out there were. Unfortunately, the rush to settlement for the relatively minor "IT mishap" shut down further inquiry that might've led to correcting more systemic problems.

I always find these things so exasperating. Sometimes I was a customer of the company at some point, but I have no idea precisely when. "Anyone who purchased something from company X during years Y to Z" -- who keeps receipts from 10-15 years ago? And my share of the settlement is likely to be just a couple of bucks. So if they think I'm in the class, I'll take it rather than waste time trying to confirm or deny.
